# Accessing FormData Values

Tags: javascript, html, form-data

I have a FormData object which I create in `javascript` from an `HTML` form like so. The `FormData` object doesn't seem very well documented (it may just be me searching the wrong things!).

```
var form = new FormData(document.getElementById("form"));
```

**My Question**

How do I access the different input values of this `FormData` object before I send it off? Eg. `form.name` accesses the value that was entered into the input with the name `form.name`.

Comment: If by 'access' you meant visually inspect, try `console.info(...myFormData);`, which apparently casted the object to an array, at least in FF.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It seems you can't get values of the form element using **`FormData`**.

> The **`FormData`** object lets you compile a set of key/value pairs to send
>   using XMLHttpRequest. **Its primarily intended for use in sending form
>   data, but can be used independently from forms in order to transmit
>   keyed data.** The transmitted data is in the same format that the form's
>   submit() method would use to send the data if the form's encoding type
>   were set to "multipart/form-data".

However you can achieve it using simple Javascript like this

```
var formElements = document.forms['myform'].elements['inputTypeName'].value;
```

Comment: Thats a shame. Would have been a lot nicer to grab them from the FormData. Thanks anyway.

Comment: **This answer is no longer correct.** As other answers point out, `FormData` can be iterated on with a `for...of` loop.

Comment: Nowadays this *is* possible. Just scroll down a few answers [to this updated solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55851018/2608515) that works now in 2022.

Answer (score 33):

First thing I don't think it's possible to build a FormData object from a form as you've specified, and to get values from the form use the method described in the accepted answer -- this is more of an addendum!

It looks like you **can** get some data out of a FormData object:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("email", "test1@test.com");
formData.append("email", "test2@test.com");
formData.get("email");
```

this will only return the *first* item for that key, in this case it will return 'test1@test.com', to get all the email addresses use the below code

```
formData.getAll("email")
```

Please see also: [MDN article on formdata get method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/get).

Answer (score 31):

[FormData.get](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/get) will do what you want and works in all browsers since around 2018-2019. Given this form:

```
<form id="form">
  <input name="inputTypeName">
</form>
```

You can access the value of that input via

```
var form = new FormData(document.getElementById("form"));
var inputValue = form.get("inputTypeName");
```

Answer (score 16):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData):

> An object implementing FormData can directly be used in a for...of
>   structure, instead of entries(): for (var p of myFormData) is
>   equivalent to for (var p of myFormData.entries())

Therefore you can access FormData values like that:

```
var formData = new FormData(myForm);

for (var p of formData) {
    let name = p[0];
    let value = p[1];

    console.log(name, value)
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Just to add to the previous solution from @Jeff Daze - you can use the `FormData.getAll("key name")` function to retrieve all of the data from the object.

Answer (score 8):

This is a solution to retrieve the key-value pairs from the FormData:

```
var data = new FormData( document.getElementById('form') );
data = data.entries();              
var obj = data.next();
var retrieved = {};             
while(undefined !== obj.value) {    
    retrieved[obj.value[0]] = obj.value[1];
    obj = data.next();
}
console.log('retrieved: ',retrieved);
```

Answer (score 7):

My solution with `for-of`

```
const formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('form'))

for (const [key, value] of formData) {
  console.log('»', key, value)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I came across an extremely simple way to convert form data into an object:

```js
  const formData = new FormData(evt.currentTarget)
  const formObject = Object.fromEntries(formData.entries()) // {}
```

> Note that for multiple entries (for ex. checkbox); you need to handle separately with `formData.getAll("favFruits")` (for example)

```js
const handleSubmit = (evt) => {
  evt.preventDefault()
  const formData = new FormData(evt.currentTarget)
  const formObject = Object.fromEntries(formData.entries())

  // caveat for multiple values
  formObject.favFruits = formData.getAll("favFruits")
  console.log(formObject)
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="handleSubmit(event)">
  <input type="text" value="James" name="firstName" required placeholder="First Name..." />
  <input type="text" name="lastName" value="Bond" required placeholder="Last Name..." />
  <label>
  <br />
  <h5>Fav Fruits</h5>
  <input type="checkbox" name="favFruits" value="watermelon" />
  Watermelon
  </label>
  <label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="favFruits" checked value="apple" />
  Apple
  </label>
  <label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="favFruits" checked value="orange" />
  Orange
  </label>
  <br />
  <br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: This is really cool because it's so minimalistic.  Currently it also calls handleSubmit when user hits "Enter" in any text input.  (I mean when I added input text boxes for my own use).  I wonder if there's a way to suppress that so it only calls it when user clicks on the submit input (i.e., when button is pressed).

Comment: HI @MarkSeagoe, glad you found the cool .  You can maybe use `<input type="button" value="Submit" />`.  This will immediately stop/suppress the native handler from getting triggered when user hits "Enter" in focused text-input on the form.  Now, to handle the form submission on the click of this new button, you need to `addEventListener("click"...)` on the button and inside that handler, you need to get the from with `document.getElementWithId("form-id")`  and use it to prepare your form-data.

Comment: Right on, thanks!!!

Comment: A one-liner to copy-paste: `Object.fromEntries([...formData.keys()].map(key => [key, formData.getAll(key)]))`. This will log everything in a dictionary, including array entries such as `<input name="item[]">`

Answer (score 3):

it will work

```js
   // let form = document.querySelector("form");
  
const form = new FormData();
  
form.append("username", "Groucho");
form.append("accountnum", 123456); 
let data = new FormData(form)
formObj = {};
for (var pair of data.entries()) {
  formObj[pair[0]] = pair[1]
}
console.log(formObj)
```

Comment: Today it gets an Error.

Comment: check your form data structure

Comment: Selva I mean when I click "Run code snippet" here it gets "Uncaught TypeError".

Answer (score 1):

If what you're trying to do is get the content of the FormData or append to it, this is what you should use:

Let's say you want to upload an image like so:

```
<input type="file" name="image data" onChange={e => 
uploadPic(e)} />
```

On change handler function:

```
const handleChange = e => {
    // Create a test FormData object since that's what is needed to save image in server

   let formData = new FormData();

    //adds data to the form object

    formData.append('imageName', new Date.now());
    formData.append('imageData', e.target.files[0]);

}
```

append: adds an entry to the creates formData object where imageData is the key and e.target.files[0] is the property

You can now send this imageData object which contains data of the image to your server for processing

but to confirm if this formData has values a simple console.log(formData)/won't do it, what you should do is this:

```
//don't forget to add this code to your on change handler 
function
for (var value of formData.values()) {
   console.log(value); 
}
```

//I hope that explains my answer, it works for vanilla JavaScript and React.js...thanks in advance for your upvote

Comment: Please edit your answer with textual information about what your code does and why it answers the question.

Comment: I've done that, if that's what you need please don't forget to up vote

Answer (score 0):

A simple HTML5 way (form to object) using the **runarberg/formsquare** library (`npm i --save formsquare`):

```js
import formsquare from "formsquare";

const valuesObject = formsquare.filter((el) => !el.disabled).parse(document.getElementById('myForm'));
//=> {"foo": "bar"}
```

https://github.com/runarberg/formsquare

Answer (score 0):

Creating a FormData object in JavaScript is quite straightforward and it's a useful tool for working with HTML forms. Here's how you can create a FormData object from an HTML form:

Assuming you have an HTML form with the id "myForm"

```
const formElement = document.getElementById('myForm');
const formData = new FormData(formElement);
```

The FormData constructor takes a reference to your HTML form element as an argument, and it automatically collects all the form fields and their values.

Once you have the formData object, you can access and manipulate the form data easily. For example, you can append additional data to it or send it via an AJAX request.

While the FormData object itself may not be as well-documented as other JavaScript features, it's part of the HTML Living Standard,

Answer (score 0):

Quite similar to [@Aakash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18606305/accessing-formdata-values/76206142#76206142)'s answer, but this one-liner will also log all array entries:

```
Object.fromEntries([...formData.keys()].map(key => [key, formData.getAll(key)]))
```

```js
const onSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const formData = new FormData(e.currentTarget);
  console.log(Object.fromEntries([...formData.keys()].map(key => [key, formData.getAll(key)])));
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="onSubmit(event)">
  <input type="text" name="age" value="23" />
  <input type="text" name="hobby[]" value="foo" />
  <input type="text" name="hobby[]" value="bar" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Another solution:
HTML:

```
<form>
<input name="searchtext"  type="search" >'
<input name="searchbtn" type="submit" value="" class="sb" >
</form>
```

JS:

```
$('.sb').click( function() {
    var myvar=document.querySelector('[name="searchtext"]').value;
    console.log("Variable value: " + myvar);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<html>
<body>
    <form id="form">
        <input type="text" value="Jane Doe" name="name" placeholder="Name" /><br>
        <input type="number" name="age" value="18" placeholder="Age" /><br>
        <input type="number" name="contact" placeholder="Contact" disabled /><br>
    </form>
    <script>
        console.log('Name : ', (formVals = document.getElementById('form')).name.value );
        // more efficient
        console.log('Age : ', formVals.age.value);
        console.log('Contact : ', formVals.contact.value);

        console.log('Name by FormData : ', (formData = new FormData(formVals)).get('name'));
        // less efficient
        console.log('Age by FormData : ', formData.get('age'));
        console.log('Contact by FormData : ', formData.get('contact'));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```