# Capture ajax request and its POST data

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to capture an ajax request and its POST-data but haven't found any way of doing it.

I've been trying with: XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open but haven't found any way of capturing the POST data using it.

I suppose this is what I'd like to do:

```
(function(open) {
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function (method, url, async) {
        this.addEventListener('readystatechange', function () {
            if(url.indexOf("the-url-i-want-to-capture") !== -1 && this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
                // do ... something ... with the POST data
            }
        }, false);
        open.call(this, method, url, async);
    };
})(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are working with native ajax `XMLHttpRequest` object, do not use prototype to access `open`, but first declare the variable and then use all the methods that it offers, like `open`, `send` etc.

Also note that you can't intercept and capture data because FormData objects are not stringifiable objects (hint: images?). only if you are using `GET` method you can see data in the `url`.

I've added example for you to see response from POST request

See this page to get you started with all the details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started

```js
(function(open) {
  // declare new http client
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  // define what to do after req finishes
  req.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(req.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) console.log( req.responseText );
  };
  // start our POST req
  req.open('POST', 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?test', true);
  // sent it
  req.send();
})();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however I don't really get how I would capture an (external, sort of) ajax request from something explained at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started

I'm capturing an ajax-request made by a (3rd party) script that I don't want to change any code in. 

The request is captured but unfortunately I don't have access to the POST data in the request.

Comment: see this answer, that's similar to what you are trying to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18606305/accessing-formdata-values

Comment: Thank for the reply again. However, I'm not trying to get the data from a form: I'm trying to get the data from an ajax-request.