# How to read external form data into an angular 2 application

Tags: angular, form-data

A redirect link with form data are sent to my angular application from an external application.

ex: Redirect Link => https://myapp/#/live (POST request)

Form data => accessToken=YxerUjwi8u0IN5jZeTECG06eipKr/npjRg0J6TNHp7LmSJG6On28gNnw4hN1wYw27GtlGWcSzhvOWnvGTtXFE

How can I get this form data into my angular application?

Comment: take a look at this answer - i think your question is more javascript specific rather than angular specific: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18606305/accessing-formdata-values

Comment: No. I am having a scenario where from other web application they are redirecting to my angular app by posting some form-data. Now I need to capture that form-data  which contains accessToken in my angular app.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass data to an Angular app without a backend, then don't use a POST request, use a GET request instead, and pass the data as query params (in the URL).

If you absolutely need to use a POST request, then you need a backend to retrieve the params, then process them and redirect to the Angular app. You have multiple choices here:

- Store the data in a database, then redirect to a specific Angular URL
- Redirect to a specific Angular URL and pass the data as query params
- ...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In the GET request instead of passing data as query params can the data be sent in request header?

Comment: No, the Angular app executes after the request is done, so it won't be able to get anything from headers. On the other hand, query params in the URL will persist until the Angular app executes and read them.

Comment: You mean there is no way to access POST request data that is sent to angular app?

Comment: You are mistaken when you write "POST data sent to angular app". The POST data is sent to your web server, which serves the angular app