# new FormData(form) Without Submitting form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, razor

I have an HTML form that includes a file. I want to be able to catch the response of the form post and edit my page according without a refresh.

To do so I am using an Ajax call that submits the form for me. However, whenever I call the `new FormData(form)` it submits the form instead of just taking the form data.

Here is the form HTML

```
<form asp-controller="Application" asp-action="UploadDocument" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="modalDocId" name="documentId" type="hidden" />
    <input id="modalAppId" name="applicationId" type="hidden" />
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="modal-display">
            <input name="documentFile" type="file" class="dropify pa-20" data-height="250" data-allowed-file-extensions="pdf jpg jpeg png" accept=".pdf,.jpg,.jpeg,.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center pb-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

And the Ajax Call

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form', function () {
    var form = $(this);
    var formData = new FormData(form);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        url: '/Application/UploadDocument',
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {

            if (data == 1) {
                debugger;
            }
            else {
                debugger;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });

    return false;
})
```

It never gets to the Ajax call, at `new FormData(form)` the form is submitted and it redirects to the result, which is just a 1 or 0.

I want the form to be submitted via Ajax so the page does not redirect but I can do things depending on the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the fact you're using a delegated event handler, `return false` will not work; it's called too late to have an effect in this case. To fix this call `preventDefault()` on the submit event directly.

There's several other issues too:

- You need to provide an Element object to the `FormData` constructor, not a jQuery object.
- `return false` in the `success` handler function is redundant and should be removed.
- `async: false` is very bad practice and needs to be removed. It's not necessary in this case anyway.
- You need to add `contentType` and `processData` options, and set them both to `false` in order for the FormData to be encoded correctly in the request.

With all that said, try this:

```js
$(document).on('submit', 'form', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var formData = new FormData(this);

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Application/UploadDocument',
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false, 
    success: function (data) {
      if (data == 1) {
        debugger;
      } else {
        debugger;
      }
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I am still getting an error with the `new FormData(form)` declaration. `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'FormData': parameter 1 is not of type 'HTMLFormElement'.`

Comment: Completely missed that issue - I've updated the answer for you

Comment: This update throws `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`

Comment: It's within the AJAX Post, the action never makes it to my back end due to this error.

Comment: Sorry, spotted more issues. I've edited the question to fix them, and give you the whole thing, corrected.

Comment: To fix the `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation` error you need to turn the form data into an object first, as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76206142/4484799

Comment: @UriahsVictor this answer is already doing that..?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Not quite, when `formData` is added to any line it will try to run, hence the `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation` error, the answer I linked shows how to handle this by converting it first